# TIN interpolation problem

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, interpolation, tin

I made a TIN interpolation of some height points but the resulting raster appears with some weird lines (like in the pic)[image]

What can i do to avoid this result?

[image]

Here are the input parameters. Sorry that my QGIS is set to Italian.

Comment: Can you post your data and a screen shot of your input parameters from QGIS??

Comment: Click the drop down arrow at interpolation method and choose TIN - triangular irregular network. If itstill does not work, please share a sample of your data, so that I could try and reproduce the error on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this problem is related as your data is sorted.

I had the same problem with TIN interpolation and this was solved when I organized my xyz file as lon, lat, attribute, being the order of values organized by longitude (from -180 to 180 degrees)